# Screw Cap design for high pressure surge vessel

Tags: design, threads

I'm designing a pressure vessel with a relatively large cap that provides access into the vessel, what recommended thread specifications is needed to maximized locking and safety against faliure or popout.

Comment: What have you found on existing high pressure vessels so far, so we don’t duplicate and waste our effort.

Comment: Well, I have seen the standards for scuba diving tanks which gets pressurized to up to 4000 psi, but I was looking for help since my case incorporate the "surge", I don't know if that matters.

Comment: What about deep diving vessels?

Comment: This is an Australian standard: "standard 3/4" NPSM (NGS) parallel thread, sealed by an O-ring, which has a 60° thread form, a pitch diameter of 0.9820 to 0.9873 in (24.94 to 25.08 mm), and a pitch of 14 threads per inch (5.5 threads per cm)."

Comment: Like submarines?

Comment: What goes deeper?

Comment: What are the other connections using?

Comment: There's only one: the cap. I don't know of anything that goes deeper than a sub, maybe ocean probes (robots).

Comment: So once you seal the cap how does any pressure surge get in there?

Comment: A gas generating reaction occur in the vessel, a really fast one I'll stress. The vessel goes from 0 to around 4500 psi in less than 1 second.

Comment: Then you won't have time to close the lid...

Comment: I won't set-off the reaction until the lid is firmly close. Just help with the thread thing will you.

Comment: I don't think that you're going to find a standard / specification for that particular use case beyond what you have already found.  I think that you're in enough of a niche to where a standard wouldn't exist.  Mike is using a Socratic method in order to gather more requirements from you.  I'd suggest using the AUS standard that you mentioned and then use a mechanical lock of some sort in order to keep the cap from rotating.